# Why does a reference not live long enough in case of "as_slice"?

Tags: rust

I cannot figure out why this code compiles:

```
fn f(v: &mut Vec<isize>) -> &[isize] {
    v.as_mut_slice()
}
```

and this does not:

```
fn f(v: &mut Vec<isize>) -> &[isize] {
    v.as_slice()
}
```

producing:

```
<anon>:2:5: 2:6 error: `v` does not live long enough
<anon>:2     v.as_slice()
             ^
<anon>:1:38: 3:2 note: reference must be valid for the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the block at 1:37...
<anon>:1 fn f(v: &mut Vec<isize>) -> &[isize] {
<anon>:2     v.as_slice()
<anon>:3 }
<anon>:1:38: 3:2 note: ...but borrowed value is only valid for the block at 1:37
<anon>:1 fn f(v: &mut Vec<isize>) -> &[isize] {
<anon>:2     v.as_slice()
<anon>:3 }
```

If I understand correctly, in either case function signature is same, and return value lifetime is equal to the input parameter one. So why "as_slice" does not work?

Comment: Hmm. Removing the `mut` and making the signature `v: &Vec<isize>` in the second case *does* allow it to compile.

Comment: It does. But I'm just trying to understand language mechanics.

Comment: Oh, I agree it's odd - I'm just adding information for whoever can help answer ;-).

Comment: This look like a bug to me. The new `&v[]` form also compiles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's a "bug" or better a limitation of the `AsSlice` trait. Since `v.as_slice()` is now unstable and will probably be removed in favor of `&v[]` (which already works as intended in your case) I will not open a bug, but I'll try explaining why the current trait does not work to the best of my knowledge.

First, look at the [definition of the `as_slice`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/slice.rs.html#614-617) that is invoked in your case.

```
impl<'a, T, U: ?Sized + AsSlice<T>> AsSlice<T> for &'a mut U {
    #[inline(always)]
    fn as_slice(&self) -> &[T] { AsSlice::as_slice(*self) }
}
```

note that as_slice is actually eliding a new lifetime. If we give it a name (`'b`) we're actually writing something like:

```
impl<'a, T, U: ?Sized + AsSlice<T>> AsSlice<T> for &'a mut U {
    #[inline(always)]
    fn as_slice<'b>(&'b self) -> &'b [T] { AsSlice::as_slice(*self) }
}
```

What we would actually want is `'b` to be the same as `'a`, but I think there was no way to express this at the time `AsSlice` was created (now this might be possible with Higher Ranked Trait Bounds). The effect of this is that, when we call `as_slice()` in your function `f`, we're returning a fresh lifetime, that can't escape `f`. This is in fact the error you're getting.

If `AsSlice` was written now, it would be using associated types and would be able to link lifetimes in the way we want. It would be something similar to this:

```
pub trait AsSlice2 {
    type Item;
    fn as_slice_2(&self) -> & [Self::Item];
}

impl<T> AsSlice2 for [T] {
    type Item = T;
    fn as_slice_2(&self) -> &[T] { &self[] }
}
```

[playpen](https://play.rust-lang.org/?code=%23!%5Ballow(unstable)%5D%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20mut%20v%20%3D%20vec!%5B1%2C2%2C3%5D%3B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20a%20%3D%20f(%26mut%20v)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20println!(%22%7B%3A%3F%7D%22%2C%20a)%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20f(a%3A%20%26mut%20Vec%3Cisize%3E)%20-%3E%20%26%5Bisize%5D%20%7B%20a.as_slice_2()%20%7D%20%0A%0Apub%20trait%20AsSlice2%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20type%20Item%3B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20as_slice_2(%26self)%20-%3E%20%26%20%5BSelf%3A%3AItem%5D%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aimpl%3CT%3E%20AsSlice2%20for%20%5BT%5D%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20type%20Item%20%3D%20T%3B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20as_slice_2(%26self)%20-%3E%20%26%5BT%5D%20%7B%20%26self%5B%5D%20%7D%0A%7D%0A)

This is similar to how as_mut_slice is currently implemented (that's why that one works)